# Accessing a private GitHub submodule

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules

On our dev and production severs we are trying to install a git repo from Github.com but running into access issues. The issue steams from having a private submodule inside the repo. It works fine for our development team because we are using organization keys but on the servers we are using deploy keys.

I understand that I can create an entry in the .ssh/config file with a different ssh key but this would require me to also update the .gitmodules file. The issue with changing the gitmodules file is the dev team would need to accommodate this on their local environments. I rather leave the .gitmodules pointing to the correct location and only do workarounds on the servers.

Ideally I could update the hostname on the servers and create a ssh confing entry. Unfortunately I tried this but my server update scripts reverts any changes and the hostname changes get reverted.

It would be sooooooo nice if GitHub allowed for deploy keys to be shared by other repos (sigh)

Any ideas or alternate options would be great!

Comment: The [GH docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/) say that you specify the deploy key in the repo - why can't you do this on the submodule? Also, can you get around the `.gitmodules` issue using the `url.<base>.insteadOf` git config?

Comment: That worked!  

**Get**  
`git config --get remote.origin.url`
  
**Set**  
`git remote set-url origin git@github-framework:[path]`
  
**SSH Config**  
`Host github-framework  HostName github.com  User git IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa.framework`